# Way of splitting spacetimes into space and time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

On several occasions, we would like to separate the components of the metric into three sets ($g_{00}$,$g_{0\alpha}$,$g_{\alpha \beta}$). Please refer to exercise $4.2$ of "Gravitation, Foundations and Frontiers" by T.Padmanabhan. In the given problem one writes the metric as $$ds^2 = -M^2(dt-M_{\alpha}dx^{\alpha})^2+\gamma_{\alpha \beta}dx^{\alpha}dx^{\beta},$$ where the functions $M^2$,${M_{\alpha}}$,$\gamma_{\alpha \beta}$ determine the metric. Hence the metric coefficients are given as $$g_{00}=-M^2;g_{0 \alpha}=M^2M_{\alpha}; g_{\alpha \beta}= \gamma_{\alpha \beta}-M^2M_{\alpha}M_{\beta}.$$ I need to show that $$g^{00}=-(M^{-2}-M_{\gamma}M^{\gamma}); g^{0 \alpha}= M^{\alpha}; g^{\alpha \beta}= \gamma^{\alpha \beta }.$$
I have tried to find the components of the inverse metric by using $g^{i k}g_{kj}= \delta^{i}_{j}$ or $g^{ji}= (-1)^{i+j}\frac{|m_{i j}|}{g}$ where $|m_{i j}|$ is the determinant of the minor of $g_{ij}$ and $g$ is the determinant of the metric, but i keep getting stuck. Here the notation pertains to that of the latin indices running from $0,1,2,3$ and the greek indices running from $1,2,3.$ Any hints or further references would be very helpful.